# JavaScript calender to accept future date only

Tags: javascript

Is there a calendar control to display only future dates?
What would the code look like?

Comment: A brief look at the docs would have answered your question. When you do read the docs, look at `minDate` as it will do what you need. @matt b posted the link below.

Comment: I know I'm just talking to myself here but... @Sakthivel, it would be courteous of you to accept answers to more of your questions and/or contribute to others' questions

Comment: @Sakthivel: "please do it for me" is rentacoder.com.

Comment: 3% on 46 questions including this one, member for 9 months. This is wrong.

Comment: @Crescent: he is looking for quick answers instead of googling it himself.

Comment: Sakthivel makes me feel so.... so.... *used*.

Answer (score 27):

The [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max) can be configured to only allow future dates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: 0});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/